# How to make a base class method non-overridable in ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop, overriding

I have some base class A with a method that is not to be overridden.

```
class A
  def dont_override_me
    puts 'class A saying, "Thank you for not overriding me!"'
  end
end
```

And another class B that extends A and tries to override the `dont_override_me` method.

```
class B < A
  def dont_override_me
    puts 'class B saying, "This is my implementation!"'        
  end
end
```

If I instantiate B and call `dont_override_me`, class B's instance method will be called.

```
b = B.new
b.dont_override_me # => class B saying, "This is my implementation!"
```

This is because of ruby's properties. Understandable.

However, how do I force the base class method `dont_override_me` to be non-overridable by it's derived classes? I could not find a keyword like `final` in java for ruby. In C++, the base class methods can be made non-virtual so that they become non-overridable by the derived classes. How do I achieve this in ruby?

Comment: You've already got answers, but I'd strongly suggest that you revisit your reasons for wanting this: it's a common idiom in some languages, like Java, but it's very much not normal behaviour in Ruby, and could cause unnecessary pain and hardship down the line.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! :) This is not really a requirement on a live project. This question popped up just like that. But restricting a derived class from overriding a method may be needed while building frameworks n stuff, I suppose. I don't have much experience there but this is my guess.

Comment: @Chirantan - your question and the answers are interesting. I'm glad you asked this! However, if I discovered that a gem or framework were actively preventing me from overriding a method, it would be a serious WTF and I would stop using that gem.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it, by hooking the change event and changing it back, but it seems a bit smelly to me:

http://scie.nti.st/2008/9/17/making-methods-immutable-in-ruby

It's one of those things that sort of defines Ruby, so fighting against it seems a little pointless imo. If someone redefines something so it breaks horribly.. that's their problem ;-)

Comment: Great, I wonder why this isn't part of standard ruby API! I mean this scenario is very much common and yet it is not handled while designing the language...

Comment: Being able to override absolutely everything is one of the core principals of Ruby, so "handling" is would kind of go against it. You know how much the purists would complain if they put this into the core of Ruby :-)

Comment: :) Agreed. But if we have to add some code to object class every time we want to do this or use a gem, thats painful too. I was thinking if  finalize method (as given by Gdeglin below), were a standard ruby API, that would have been great. This scenario must common while building frameworks in ruby

Comment: Remember though, this still doesn't protect you fully.  Anyone who wanted to could require 'immutable' before they require your library, and redefine immutable_method as an alias for public.  Ruby is open.  Fundamentally open.

Comment: Then we will need to make immutable method immutable :)

Comment: I dont think that word means what you think it means ;)

Comment: Oh is it? From "define: immutable" on google - not subject or susceptible to change or variation in form or quality or nature. This is what I think immutable means... In this context, this means the method is not supposed to be changed/overridden. Please correct me if I am wrong, I'm only a student

Comment: Immutable effectively just means "cannot be changed", so the usage is just fine in my book :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to do it:
http://www.thesorensens.org/2006/10/06/final-methods-in-ruby-prevent-method-override/

This has also been packaged into a gem called "finalizer" (gem install finalizer)

This makes use of the method_added callback and compares the new method name with a list of methods that you wish to make `final`.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend:

```
class A #This is just as you've already defined it.
  def dont_override_me
    puts 'class A saying, "Thank you for not overriding me!"'
  end
end

module BehaviorForB
  def dont_override_me
    puts 'class B saying, "This is my implementation!"'        
  end

  def greet
    "Hello, Friend."
  end
end

class B < A
  include BehaviorForB
end

b = B.new
b.dont_override_me #=> class A saying, "Thank you for not overriding me!"
b.greet #=> Hello, Friend.
```

By keeping B's methods tucked away in an mixin, you get exactly what you desire.  Any method of B's methods that are not already in A will be available.  Methods that are already in A will not be overridden.

Comment: Actually when I run your code, `b.dont_override_me` return `"This is my implementation!"`. I'm wondering if this is because the answer is old and probably use an older version of Ruby. I tested on 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

One way to prevent a method from being overridden by a subclass (but not recommend) :

```
class Class
  def frozen_method(method)
    if class_variable_defined?(:@@__frozen_methods__)
      add= class_variable_get(:@@__frozen_methods__) | [method]
      class_variable_set(:@@__frozen_methods__,add)
    else
      class_variable_set(:@@__frozen_methods__,[method])
    end
    class << self
      def inherited(child)
        def method_added(method)
          if class_variable_get(:@@__frozen_methods__).include? method
            send(:remove_method, method)
            error="Cannot change method #{method} because it's not overridde"
            raise TypeError, error
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  def hello
    'hello'
  end
  def foo
    'foo'
  end

  frozen_method :foo
end

class Bar < Foo
  def foo
    'new foo'
  end
end

#=> TypeError: Cannot change method foo because it's not overridde

Bar.new.foo  #=> 'foo'
```

Warning: this example is not complete. If you add `frozen_method` for a previously defined method in the subclass, when this method will be modified in the subclass, it will lose its implementation.